# GNU Radio build error "No rule to make target "filter_generated_includes', needed by 'docs/doxygen/xml

Tags: gnuradio

I am running CentOs 6.5 i686 and trying to install GNU Radio.  I made a build directory and executed "sudo cmake ../" which resulted in the following:

```
######################################################
-- # Gnuradio enabled components                         
-- ######################################################
--   * python-support
--   * testing-support
--   * volk
--   * doxygen
--   * sphinx
--   * gnuradio-runtime
--   * gr-blocks
--   * gnuradio-companion
--   * gr-fec
--   * gr-fft
--   * gr-filter
--   * gr-analog
--   * gr-digital
--   * gr-atsc
--   * gr-audio
--   * gr-channels
--   * gr-noaa
--   * gr-pager
--   * gr-qtgui
--   * gr-uhd
--   * gr-utils
--   * gr-vocoder
--   * gr-fcd
--   * gr-wavelet
--   * gr-wxgui
-- 
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio disabled components                        
-- ######################################################
--   * gr-ctrlport
--   * gr-comedi
--   * gr-trellis
--   * gr-video-sdl
--   * gr-zeromq
-- 
-- Using install prefix: /usr/local
-- Building for version: 3.7.4 / 3.7.4
-- Configuring done
```

Warning: Source file "/usr/local/gnuradio/gnuradio-3.7.4/gr-digital/lib/header_payload_demux_impl.cc" is listed multiple times for target "gnuradio-digital".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/gnuradio/gnuradio-3.7.4/build

Then I executed "sudo make" which resulted in the following error:

```
[alinux build]$ sudo ldconfig
[alinux build]$ sudo make
Scanning dependencies of target volk
[  0%] Building C object volk/lib/CMakeFiles/volk.dir/constants.c.o
Linking C shared library libvolk.so
[  2%] Built target volk
Linking CXX executable test_all
[  2%] Built target test_all
Linking CXX executable volk-config-info
[  2%] Built target volk-config-info
Linking CXX executable volk_profile
[  2%] Built target volk_profile
[  2%] Built target pygen_python_volk_modtool_42925
[  2%] Built target pygen_python_volk_modtool_fe100
[  2%] Built target digital_generated_includes
[  2%] Built target pmt_generated
[  3%] Built target blocks_generated_includes
[  3%] Built target filter_generated_includes
[  3%] Built target analog_generated_includes
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `filter_generated_includes', needed by `docs/doxygen/xml'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [docs/doxygen/CMakeFiles/doxygen_target.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[alinux build]$
```

I have already built doxygen and it's in my path, I don't know what else could be wrong?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The warning about the dublette file sounds like the CMake initialization run went wrong. Usually, these kinds of errors go away by purging your build directory and running cmake again.

Also, *never* run cmake with `sudo`, as it is not necessary, and might potentially break things. You will need root privileges only when installing, and only if you're installing into a place where your normal user can't place files. The normal workflow is

```
#in GNU Radio source tree root folde
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j3
sudo make install
```